# Fixing sidebar on my project

Tags: html, css, css-float, fixed

i have problem to fix sidebar on RIGHT side of my project. you can look it [here](http://stefanrepac.com/PD/digitalna_stampa.php)
so navigation and sidebar need to be fixed, and just main content to be scroling
it need to look like this :

```
#sidebar { background-color: #EEEEEE; float: right; width: 451px; height: 100%; position: fixed;}
```

if someone have solution i will be grateful

Comment: add this to CSS: top:0;bottom:0;

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/89vgN/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite simple actually. And you were not completely off. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/89vgN) here

**HTML**

```
<div class="sidebar">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width:100px;
    background: red;
    z-index:10;
}
```

Comment: Thank you man, you help me a loth. Obviously i need to learn more :D